# How to make content available for premium React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

on my react-native app I would like to have premium content for people who paid a subscription.

My issue is how I make the content to display as unavailable(if you are not premium ) and the same as the other content if you are premium. Basically I would like the premium content to be displayed with a "lock overlay" on it for non-premium users.

However, I do not know how I set this conditional. It is a matter of state? If yes where should be positioned this state considering that is unidirectional?

Just to be clear I will have premium and non premium content

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble in a project, i was should show a screen if user was supervisor, and show another screen if wasn't supervisor.

I used `react-dynamic-import`, basically i split my main project in 3 parts:

1. Employee's Screen - The screen with access and components if user wasn't supervisor.
2. Supervisor's Screen - The screen with access and components if user was supervisor.
3. Default screen - The screen that would appear regardless of whether the user is a supervisor or not, and pull with `react-dynamic-import` your must screen, if user was supervisor i pull Supervisor's Screen, if wasn't supervisor, pull Employee's Screen

You can save a hash in cookie session and read this cookie in JS and validate with REST API, and the return of REST API is the path where are the component Premium, like that:

```js
// getting hash from cookie
const userHash = document.cookie.replace(/^.*;?user-hash=([^;]+);?.*$/, '$1');

// generate api LINK with
const apiLink = `/API/V1.0/checkuser?hash=${encodeURI(hash)}`;

/* getting value where are path is premium or isn't premium, in my case i'am using Ajax Request and my API returns a JSON like :
{"path": "pathWhereAreComponentPremium"}
*/
const pathComponent = (await $.get(apiLink)).path;

const loader = () => import(pathComponent);

// Load component dynamically
var Component = ReactDynamicImport({loader});

// ...
```

In `Component` are the component if user are or aren't premium.

**Edit 1:**
Forgive my english, i'am brazilian, and i'm learning.

**Edit 2:**

If you want just render a component by conditional analises, you can do this:

```js
const App = (props) => {

    const [isPremium, setPremium] = React.useState(false);

    const handleButtonPremium = () => (setPremium(!isPremium));

    return (<>
        <div>
            T-Shirt
            {isPremium ? <button>Get</button> : <button>Buy $1.5</button>}
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleButtonPremium}>
            {isPremium ? "Cancel Premium assign" : "Get Premium assign"}
        </button>
    </>)
}
```

See more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, i will do some research. However I was thinking is a matter of state: true/false and according to these conditions to make the content available or not, but I am not sure if it's the right way

Comment: So, i think that this can help you man.
Link: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html, you can manager if component will render or not, I will edit my answer explain this